# How to play video of dropbox directly in our application

Tags: html, html5-video, dropbox

I want to play 4 to 5 video from my dropbox account in to my website.

This is my code:

```
<video controls="controls" height="480" width="640">
  <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/393c52vimvnvr7n/devinejamz-partnership.mp4?dl=1" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
```

2 Videos are successfully playing with this code but 3 videos show below error.

My Video stops playing after sometimes.I dont know why and shows error as below:

**No Video with supported format and mime type found**.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem??

Comment: It worked just fine and from start to end.. which browser you are using to test the website?

Comment: I am using mozilla.Please see my updated question.only 1 video works works with this question but others are not working

Comment: I found this on the DROPBOX website : https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/487

apparently a movie longer than 15min will automatically stop streaming and the user has to download it.

Comment: My all videos are not more than 3 minutes

Comment: @Pyere:it is not working in chrome

Comment: yeah i know i am still looking for a solution. sorry to keep you waiting

Comment: @Pyere:it is ok.dont say sorry

Comment: Is this one of the videos that does or doesn't work? Your sample seems to work for me in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/jonso6hf/ Can you provide one that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Copy the drop box video link, then replace www.dropbox.com with dl.dropboxusercontent.com

Thus the URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgbdbgdgb/file.mp4?dl=0

will become: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dgbdbgdgb/file.mp4?dl=0

Then embed the updated URL to your video player tag.

Source: Visit: [link](https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-create-code-to-embed-a-dropbox-video/21259/2)